# return JSON from AWS Lambda Function in C#

Tags: c#, aws-lambda

Problem: Output looks like this [{\"FirstName\":\"William Smith\"}]"

Question: How can I return a string that has well formatted JSON from an AWS Lambda Function written in C#?

Details:

1. I have an AWS Lambda Function written in C#
2. The return type is "string"
3. The intention is to consume the return type as JSON
4. This is what the C# Lambda function is coded to return:

   string TestJsonEvent = "[{\"FirstName\":\"William Smith\"}]";
           return TestJsonEvent;

When the Lambda function executes; it returns:
"[{\"FirstName\":\"William Smith\"}]"

5. Even this variation returns the same:

   string TestJsonEvent = @"[{""FirstName"":""William Smith""}]";
           return TestJsonEvent;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Amazon has examples in their [announcement for C# support](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-c-sharp-support-for-aws-lambda/) and [Lambda Function Handler](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/dotnet-programming-model-handler-types.html) documentation.

Relevant bits:

> #### Handling Standard Data Types
>
> All other types, as listed below, require you to specify a serializer.
>
> - Primitive .NET types (such as string or int).
> - Collections and maps -
>     IList, IEnumerable, IList, Array, IDictionary, IDictionary
> - POCO types (Plain old CLR objects)
> - Predefined AWS event types
> - For asynchronous invocations the return-type will be ignored by
>     Lambda. The return type may be set to void in such cases.
> - If you are
>     using .NET asynchronous programming, the return type can be Task and
>     Task types and use async and await keywords. For more information,
>     see [Using Async in C# Functions with AWS Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/dotnet-programming-model-handler-types.html#dot-net-async).
>
> Unless your function
>   input and output parameters are of type `System.IO.Stream`, you will
>   need to serialize them. AWS Lambda provides a default serializer that
>   can be applied at the assembly or method level of your application, or
>   you can define your own by implementing the `ILambdaSerializer`
>   interface provided by the `Amazon.Lambda.Core` library.
>
> To add the default serializer attribute to a method, first add a dependency on `Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json`[...]

Install the [Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json/)[1] NuGet package and import a reference the `Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json` namespace.

```
public class Sample
{
    [LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]
    public object Test()
    {
        return new { FirstName = "William Smith" };
    }
}
```

[1]: [Github link](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet)

Comment: This "documentation" is a disaster. "All other types" -- other than  the ones listed below? Other than what?   What JSON would your example output? What if I need a dash in the property name, like "Content-Type"?